# Can I use HTML 5 <nav> for footer links , which is not a primary navigation?

Tags: css, xhtml, html, accessibility, semantic-markup

Can I use HTML 5 `<nav>` for footer links, which is not a primary navigation? Or should it  be used once in a page?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — only sections that consist of major navigation blocks are appropriate for the nav  element. In particular, it is common for footers to have a short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of service, the home page, and a copyright page. **The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases, without a nav element.**

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element

Answer (score 1):

Remember, though, that there is no limit to the number of nav tags you can use in a page. If you have three main navigations, you can use three nav tags.

Comment: you mean 3 different navigation links or same?

Comment: Different groups of links (might be the same links, if you repeat the main navigation in different places of the page, or different links, for example the first level of navigation and the second level) inside of different nav tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct tag, if it's not navigation, then don't use `<nav>`.

Use the `<footer>` tag: [HTML5 footer tag](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_footer_tag.cfm).